# Get YOUR_APP_ID or create app for Company Page

Tags: facebook, authentication

all!

I have Company Page on Facebook. Now I need to do login on my website. But I can't visit https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ through my Company Page account, it redirected to my page. With my private account it works correctly.

How I can to create app for my Company Page?

Comment: Please check here - http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account